# How to switch to different maven version using cmd in windows?

Tags: maven

I have maven 3.8.6 installed in my machine, but when i say maven -version in my cmd it shows 3.0.4. How to swicth to 3.8.6 using cmd?

even my maven_home in environment variables points to 3.8.6.

below is the error stack

BUILD FAILURE
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) on project ih-pmsc-outbound: The plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0 requires Maven version 3.1.0 -> [Help 1]

Comment: Remove any Maven related environment variable except the entry in PATH... meaning to point to the bin directory of your Maven installation...